# How to differentiate loaders in store?

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have a `loader` component:

```
// loader.component.ts

export class LoaderComponent implements OnInit {
  loader$: Observable<Loader>

  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {
    this.loader$ = this.store.pipe(select(selectLoader))
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

```
// loader.component.html
<p [hidden]='!(loader$ | async)'>loader!</p>
```

And the store implementation is like this:

```
// loader-state.actions.ts

export const setLoader = createAction(
  '[Loader] Set loader',
  (loader: Loader) => ({ loader })
)
```

```
// loader-state.redcure.ts

const initialState: Readonly<Loader> = false

export const loaderReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(LoaderActions.setLoader, (state, { loader }) => loader),
)
```

```
// loader-state.selector.ts

export const selectLoader = createSelector(
  (state: AppState) => state.loader,
  (loader: Loader) => loader
);
```

I want to use the loader in different components but the state is global. So if I have multiple instance of the `loader` component in my application and I set it to true in 1 component, all the loaders will be set to true.

How can I differentiate between different component instances?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, but I'm not sure if it's the best.

I added a `Input` in my `loader` component:

```
// loader.component.ts

export class LoaderComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() parentComponent?: string;

  loading?: boolean

  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {
    this.store.pipe(select(selectLoader)).subscribe((loader) => {
      this.loading = loader.loading && loader.parentComponent === this.parentComponent
    })
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Now I can pass a string from the parent component, and I've updated my store dispatches to include a string:

```
this.store.dispatch(setLoader({loading: true, parentComponent: 'uploadFile'}))
```

So now when a component dispatches a loader state it will also add a string (name of the parent component) and that will be checked in the loader component to show the correct loader instance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having one loading property, I think it would be better to have a loading status per reducer, or even per entity. That way, you can track each status individually.

Comment: Perhaps set a loading value in the patent component that resolves the days request and pass that value to the loader component. Yes I think that's much better.